# How to Connect Two CQRobot Ocean Non-Contact Water/Liquid Level Sensors (CQRSENYW001) to Arduino UNO REV3 (A000066)?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, wires, breadboard, arduino-setup

I am a complete beginner trying my hand at a home automation project.

Part of my setup includes using an Arduino UNO REV3 (A000066), and connecting two CQRobot Ocean Non-Contact Water/Liquid Level Sensors (CQRSENYW001).

There is great documentation for the sensor:

http://www.cqrobot.wiki/index.php/Non-Contact_Water/Liquid_Level_Sensor_SKU:_CQRSENYW001

And setting up one sensor is a breeze (see setup in image below):

[image: Sensor to Arduino]

- Red Wire to 5V
- Black Wire to GND
- Green Wire (Output) to 7

Since there is only one 5V on the Arduino (and since the project could expand), it sounds like I need to use a breadboard to allow for expansion.

I used the following video to connect the Arduino to the breadboard for power:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ia7gkgSor78

**Now to connect the two sensors, do I just need to put the Black and Red Dupont Wires from the sensors anywhere in the - and + columns on the breadboard and connect the green wires back to the Arduino for the output in 6 and 7?**

***In other words, does the setup look correct below?***

[image: Sensor Setup]

I have noticed that doing this seems to work for the most part (there is power) for the sensor, but I just want to make sure I am doing this right. Thanks!

Comment: if it works correctly, then you are doing it right

Comment: See my answer to your post in the arduino forum.

Comment: My answer to this question is there. I am curious why are you using the same question on two forums.